# Is it possible to run ROS2 Humble and Ubuntu 22.04 on a Jetson Nano Orin (other than through Docker)?

Tags: ros2, ubuntu, ros-humble, jetson

is it possible to run ubuntu 22.04 to install and run ROS2 on a Jetson Nano Orin? I have mainly seen solutions using Docker but it would be much easier for me to not have to go through docker and better for my use case, as I will be using RViz and Gazebo a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build from source, I have a video about this actually

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQLPupPkQiU